# Using Apache-Spark to analyze time series

Tags: python, apache-spark, time-series, pyspark

I have very large time series data, the data format is:
(arrival_time, key, value), the unit of time is sec, for example:

```
0.01, k, v
0.03, k, v
....
1.00, k, v
1.10, k, v
1.20, k, v
1.99, k, v
2.00, k, v
...
```

What I need to do is to get the number of lines per second of the whole data.
By now, I use pySpark and my code is like:

```
linePerSec = []
lo = rdd.take(1)[0]
hi = lo + 1.0
end = rdd.collect()[-1][0]
while(hi < end):
     number = rdd.filter(lambda (t, k, v): t >= lo and t < hi).count()
     linePerSec.append(number)
     lo = hi
     hi = lo + 1.0
```

But it's very slow, even slower than just going through the data line by line in a for loop. I guess it's because rdd.filter() goes through the whole rdd to find the lines that meet the filter's condition. But for time series, we don't need to go through the data after the hi boundary in my code. Is there any solutions to let spark to stop going through rdd in my situation? 
Thanks!

Comment: can you  post your expected output? i can't quite work out what you're trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First lets create some dummy data:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(
    [(0.01, "k", "v"),
    (0.03, "k", "v"),
    (1.00, "k", "v"),
    (1.10, "k", "v"),
    (1.20, "k", "v"),
    (1.99, "k", "v"),
    (2.00, "k", "v"),
    (3.10, "k", "v"),
    (4.50, "k", "v")])
```

extract time field from a RDD:

```
def get_time(x):
    (start, _, _) = x
    return start

times = rdd.map(get_time)
```

Next we'll need a function mapping from a time to a key:

```
def get_key_(start):
    offset = start - int(start)
    def get_key(x):
        w = int(x) + offset
        return w if x >= w else int(x - 1) + offset
    return get_key
```

find the minimum and maximum time

```
start = times.takeOrdered(1)[0]
end = times.top(1)[0]
```

generate an actual key function:

```
get_key = get_key_(start)
```

and compute mean

```
from operator import add

total = (times
  .map(lambda x: (get_key(x), 1))
  .reduceByKey(add)
  .values()
  .sum())

time_range = get_key(end) - get_key(start) + 1.0

mean = total / time_range

mean
## 1.8
```

Quick check:

- [0.01, 1.01): 3
- [1.01, 2.01): 4
- [2.01, 3.01): 0
- [3.01, 4.01): 1
- [4.01, 5.01): 1

It gives 9 / 5 = 1.8

Data frame equivalent can look like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, col, sum, lit, min, max

# Select only arrival times
arrivals = df.select("arrival_time")

# This is almost identical as before
start = df.agg(min("arrival_time")).first()[0]
end = df.agg(max("arrival_time")).first()[0]

get_key = get_key_(start)
time_range = get_key(end) - get_key(start) + 1.0

# But we'll need offset as well
offset = start - int(start)

# and define a bucket column
bucket = (col("arrival_time") - offset).cast("integer") + offset

line_per_sec = (df
    .groupBy(bucket)
    .agg(count("*").alias("cnt"))
    .agg((sum("cnt") / lit(time_range)).alias("mean")))

line_per_sec.show()

 ## +----+
 ## |mean|
 ## +----+
 ## | 1.8|
 ## +----+
```

Please note that this is very similar to [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33730575/1560062) provided by [Nhor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4248237/nhor) with two main differences:

- uses the same start logic as your code
- correctly handles empty intervals

Comment: Thank you very much, changing the time to it's integer part, then groupByKey, very clever! Based on your idea, a more concise way is   rdd.map(lambda (t ,k, v): (int(t), k, v)).

Comment: Tuple parameter unpacking is concise but has been removed with [PEP-3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) and is no longer a valid syntax in 3.x. So it is not something you really want in your code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the first I would floor the time values:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = df.select(floor(col('arrival_time')).alias('arrival_time'))
```

Now you have your `arrival_time` floored and you're ready to count number of lines in each second:

```
df = df.groupBy(col('arrival_time')).count()
```

Now when you have counted the lines in each second, you can get all the rows and divide thier sum by count to get average lines per second:

```
lines_sum = df.select(sum(col('count')).alias('lines_sum')).first().lines_sum
seconds_sum = df.select(count(col('arrival_time')).alias('seconds_sum')).first().seconds_sum
result = lines_sum / seconds_sum
```

Comment: That is close but doesn't cover all the original logic. Note that OP counts by second since initial time. It means simple `floor` wont be enough.